# Как получить значение определенного элемента массива, а не его адрес?

Tags: c, массивы

Задача заключалась в том, чтобы найти максимальный элемент массива и вывести 5 чисел, что следуют после него в счете.

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
        int arr[5];
        int size = 5;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            scanf_s("%d", &arr[i]);
        }
        int max = arr[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
            if (arr[i] > max) 
                max = arr[i];

        printf("Max=%d\n", &max);
        int k=1;
  
                do
                {
                  int j= max + 1;
                    k = k + 1;
                    printf("Next: %d\n", &j);
                } while (k != 6);

    }
```

я понимаю, что выводятся адреса, но как получить значения? помогите, запутався :С

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы прям и выводите адрес

```
printf("Max=%d\n", &max);
```

амперсанд в данном случае как раз и означает - возврати адрес. Поэтому, пишем так

```
printf("Max=%d\n", max);
```

Что происходит в цикле в конце - не совсем понятно, но если хотелось просто вывести массив, то это так

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
```

Comment: В цикле (в вопросе) попытка вывести 5 чисел от max+1 до max+5

Comment: возможно. но я не уверен

Comment: да, так, я планировал рекурсивную функцию добавить, а как иначе вывести следующих 5 чисел после максимального из массива-не знаю

Comment: а вы этого не можете сделать. Если даже максимальное - это самое первое, то за ним будет только 4 числа (весь массив только на 5 элементов). Попробуйте более точно сформулировать задачу

Comment: последующие 5 не из массива, просто по натуральному ряду. например, максимальное 6, тогда последующие 5: 7,8,9,10,11

Comment: я так понимаю, это в фор надо запихнуть

Comment: усе, дописав)   int k = 5;
   
    for (int i=0; i < k; i++)
    {
        int j = max + 1;
        max = j;
        printf("Next: %d\n", j);
    }

Answer (score 1):

Что если сделать счетчик, которой определит номер элемента max и потом сделать for с этого элемента до конца?

Comment: действительно, как вариант, сейчас попробую)

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы вывести не адрес, а значение нужно писать не `printf("Max=%d\n", &max);`, а `printf("Max=%d\n", max);`. То есть без `&`.

Так же вот пример, как можно вывести дальше 5 чисел после максимального:

```
int k = max + 1;
while(k <= max + 5){
    printf("Next: %d\n", k);
    k = k + 1;
}
```

Полный код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int arr[5];
    int size = 5;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    int max = arr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
        if (arr[i] > max) {
            max = arr[i];
        }

    printf("Max=%d\n", max);
    int k = max + 1;
    while(k <= max + 5){
        printf("Next: %d\n", k);
        k = k + 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В общем случае: если у вас известен адрес, то значение по этому адресу можно получить с помощью оператора разыменования `*`.

В этом смысле вы могли бы написать

```
printf("Max=%d\n", *&max);
```

и получить то, что вам требуется. Опять же, операторы `*` и `&`, так сказать, взаимно друг друга компенсируют, так что `*&` можно удалить, и получить

```
printf("Max=%d\n", max);
```

P.S. Ну, раз тут все пишут еще и свои решения исходной задачи, то...

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
#define SIZE 20
    int arr[SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        arr[i] = rand()%100;

    int max = arr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < SIZE; i++)
        if (arr[i] > max)
            max = arr[i];

    printf("Max = %d\n", max);

    for(int k = 1; k <= 5; ++k)
        printf("Next %d\n", max+k);
}
```